# Status 500 in nest js

Tags: error-handling, nest, http-status-code-500

I was studying nest js and when I create my api with prism my api sends error 500

I tried to see something in stack overflow, but I couldn't do anything to resolve my error

```
// Book Controller
  @Post()
  async create(@Body() data: BookDTO) {
    return await this.bookService.create(data);
  }
```

```
// Book Service
  async create(data: BookDTO) {
    return await this.prisma.book.create({ data });
  }
```

This appeared in my logs

```
[Nest] 1188  - 06/11/2023, 11:46:09   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 
Invalid `this.prisma.book.create()` invocation in
C:\Users\gamer\Documents\nest\api\src\modules\book\book.service.ts:10:35

   7 constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}
   8
   9 async create(data: BookDTO) {
→ 10   return await this.prisma.book.create({
         data: {
       +   title: String
         }
       })

Argument `title` is missing.
PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `this.prisma.book.create()` invocation in
C:\Users\gamer\Documents\nest\api\src\modules\book\book.service.ts:10:35

   7 constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}
   8
   9 async create(data: BookDTO) {
→ 10   return await this.prisma.book.create({
         data: {
       +   title: String
         }
       })

Argument `title` is missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some knowledge about JavaScript.

the error message you're seeing indicates that the title property is missing in the data object you're passing to this.prisma.book.create() method in your Book Service.

Here's your current code snippet:

```
async create(data: BookDTO) {
return await this.prisma.book.create({
 data: {
   // title: String <-- This line is commented out
 }
  });
}
```

It seems that the title property is commented out. You need to make sure that you include the title property in the data object with the appropriate value from your BookDTO. Assuming that BookDTO has a title property, you should uncomment the line:

```
async create(data: BookDTO) {
  return await this.prisma.book.create({
    data: {
      title: data.title, // Include the title property
      // Other properties from BookDTO
    }
  });
}
```

I think i helped solve your problem